# How to read a file into a C program on Linux?

Tags: c, linux

What is the difference between running an already compiled C program with `a.out file_name_here` and `a.out < file_name_here`?

I remember something about Linux pipelines, but I cannot remember how to make the `a.out` file accept a file using the `<` symbol.

Basically what I am asking is this: how does the C code look for a C program that:

1. file_name_here is a text file with "hello world" as content
2. terminal gets "a.out < file_name_here" in command line
3. terminal shows output: "hello world"

Comment: `a.out file_name` passes file_name as an argument to the program, but `a.out < file_name` pipes the contents of `file_name` to `a.out` via `stdin`. This isn't really a programming question - unix.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask. It also has nothing to do with `c` in particular.

Comment: @IskarJarak: the `<` redirects rather than pipes the contents of the file.  The program reads directly from the file; it is not given a pipe to read.

Answer (score 4):

`a.out file_name_here` passes "file_name_here" as an argument.

`a.out < file_name_here` is processed by the shell and presents the contents of "file_name_here" to the program on its "stdin".

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you type `a.out < filename`, the shell handles the I/O redirection.  The program is run with its standard input coming from the named file instead of from the terminal.  When you type `a.out filename`, the program must deal with opening the file, reading it (and preferably closing it too).  Neither of these examples uses a pipe.  You could write `cat file1 file2 file3 | a.out` which would use a pipe and supply the contents of the three files as the standard input to the program.

Many programs on Unix systems are filters.  If they are given file names to process, those are read.  If they are given no file names, then they read standard input instead.  An example of such a program is `grep`; other examples include `cat` and `sort`.

The general solution, in outline, is:

```
extern void process_file(FILE *fp); // Where the real work is done

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    if (argc == 1)
        process_file(stdin);
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            FILE *fp = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (fp == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading\n",
                        argv[0], argv[i]);
                rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            else
            {
                process_file(fp);
                fclose(fp);
            }
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

This will process any command line arguments as files to be read, resorting to reading standard input if no files are specified on the command line.  There are legions of extra tweaks you can make to this outline.  You can easily add option processing with `getopt()` (or `getopt_long()` if you're using GNU), and you can treat a file name of `-` as standard input if you wish.  You can exit on failure to open a file if you think that's appropriate (sometimes it is; sometimes it isn't — `grep` doesn't, for example).  You can pass the file name to the `process_file()` function.  You can have the `process_file()` function report success failure, and track whether everything worked, exiting with zero only if all the operations were successful.

Answer (score 0):

Just realized the problem I had. The `<` symbol means that the shell replaces normal user input in C with the content of the file, so all the normal calls such as `fgets` and `sscanf` work on it.